# How to use result of CASE in WHERE?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have the query like this:

```
select case when product.name = "milk" then product.price
            when product.name = "juice" and product.price > 3 then product.description
       end as product_condition
from product 
where product_condition = 10;
```

But after that, I have error, that the this column PRODUCT_CONDITION not found. So how is it possible to do?

Comment: Your `CASE` expression outputs either a price (a number) or a description (text).  This doesn't make sense.  Please add sample data.

Comment: you have 2 possible result of your production_condition, 1 is price (money) and the other one is description (varchar), but your condition is expecting INT

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways that you can do it, you can either incorporate the case statement within the where clause or you can apply it within a subquery as below

```
select case when product.name = "milk" then product.price
when product.name = "juice" and product.price > 3 then product.description
end as product_condition
from product 
where case when product.name = "milk" then product.price
when product.name = "juice" and product.price > 3 then product.description
end = 10;
```

OR

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
select case when product.name = "milk" then product.price
when product.name = "juice" and product.price > 3 then product.description
end as product_condition
from product 
) Conditioned
where Conditioned.product_condition = 10;
```

Comment: you have 2 possible result of your production_condition, 1 is price (money) and the other one is description (varchar), but your condition is expecting INT

Comment: But can I do at the first select and then where in result of select?

Comment: The case statement looks wrong, but regardless, this solution looks right.